# How to select DOM elements with number value id using D3

Tags: d3.js

All:

I wonder how do I select a DIV element with id="1" in D3, I can do it in jQuery, but when I turn to D3, it gives error like:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on
>   'Document': 'div.chart#1' is not a valid selector

```
<div id="1"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The id TAG must start with letter, but you can use this:

```
d3.select('[id="1"]').append("div");
```

[This is the example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4zgwu83/36/)

[And here the technical explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/4031083)

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation when trying to select an element by id using d3 failed with the error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: 'obj_id' is not a valid selector`.

My work around was to define a function

```js
const d3Select = (id) => d3.select(document.getElementById(id))
```

an example of usage:

```js
const dom = d3Select('obj_id')
   .attr('class','warning')
```

and it works just fine

Answer (score -1):

If you gave it an ID, you can select it directly by ID. You don't need to specify div in the selector.

```
d3.select('#1')
.foo()
```

Comment: doesn't work for me either. I can select first object by type (in my case 'select') but not by id.  EDIT: it works when I prefix the id with #